# How can I select values from different rows depending on the most recent entry date, all for the same employee ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Basically I have a table which is used to hold employee work wear details. It is formed of the columns:

```
EmployeeID, CostCentre, AssociateLevel, IssueDate, TrouserSize, TrouserLength, TopSize & ShoeSize.
```

An employee can  be assigned a pair of trousers, a top and shoes at the same time or only one or two pieces of clothing. As we all know peoples sizes and employee levels can change which is why I need help really. Different types of employees (associatelevels) require different colours of clothing but you can ignore this part. Everytime an employee receives an item of clothing a new row will be inserted into the table with an input date. I need to be able to select the most recent clothes size for each item of clothing for each employee.

It is not necessary for all the columns to hold values because an employee could receive trousers or poloshirts at different times in the year.

So for example if employee '54664LSS' was given a pair of 'XL' trousers and a 'L' top on 24/03/11 but then received a 'M' top on 26/05/10. The input of these items would be help on two different rows obviously. So if I wanted to select the most recent clothing for each clothes category. Then the values of the 'M' sized top and the 'L' sized trousers would need to be returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm pretty stuck :(. Thanks.

Comment: If you have female employees I'd treat the generated report as confidential information :-)

Comment: A doubt. Why new rows are inserted when update can solve your issue easily? Of course, you can do nothing if it exists like that already or it is some sort of design decision for logging or archiving etc.

Comment: @blntechie - I assume an audit history is very important. Of course a current clothes table cold also be an approach to use.

Comment: @James Yes, i accept that as i mentioned already. Just wanted to know whether they have already implemented CDC or some other audit tracking technique so that they can just simply update.

Comment: Hey, yeah i posed this question to the people requesting it but they said they want a record of every piece of clothing that has been received. No CDC,not sure what that is for a start? The current system is just a paper record. There is a table for current work wear and a table for work wear history

Comment: @user321185, your question is not that good. you do not provide enough details to solve.  I'm sure this is a very simple join query, but how can anyone here solve it without having any real info about your tables.  Sure you provide the columns names for one table, but with no explanation of what is in there.  is it one row per employee or one row every time some cloths are issued to an employee or something else.  In a comment you mention `a table for current work wear and a table for work wear history`, it might be helpfull of you elaborate on what is stored in these tables.

Comment: @user321185 CDC captures all your changes on a sql server table. For a starter on CDC, check this link http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/. If you don't use SQL Server 2008, it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @blntechie yes I have SQL 2005 but thanks anyway. @KM I have made some changes hope it makes more sense. The current workwear table would hold sizes for the current employees so that clothes can be reordered to the correct size. The history table would hold an archive of all employee work wear that has been distributed, past and present. But I have solved this issue now by changing the way the tables are constructed. So thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always easier to answer if you can give a schema definition and some sample data, and the expected output, rather than a commentary. I've attempted a schema definition, haven't got any sample data, and *think* that this answer gives what you want:

```
/*create table Clothing (
 EmployeeID int not null,
 CostCentre varchar(10) not null,
 AssociateLevel int not null,
 IssueDate datetime not null,
 TrouserSize int null,
 TrouserLength int null,
 TopSize varchar(4) null,
 ShoeSize varchar(10) null
)*/
go
with Trousers as (
 select
  EmployeeID,
  CostCentre,
  AssociateLevel,
  IssueDate,
  TrouserSize,
  TrouserLength,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY IssueDate Desc) as RowNum
 from
  Clothing
 where
  TrouserSize is not null
), Tops as (
 select
  EmployeeID,
  CostCentre,
  AssociateLevel,
  IssueDate,
  TopSize,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY IssueDate Desc) as RowNum
 from
  Clothing
 where
  TopSize is not null
), Shoes as (
 select
  EmployeeID,
  CostCentre,
  AssociateLevel,
  IssueDate,
  ShoeSize,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY IssueDate Desc) as RowNum
 from
  Clothing
 where
  ShoeSize is not null
)
select
  COALESCE(tr.EmployeeID,tops.EmployeeID,sh.EmployeeID) as EmployeeID,
  tr.CostCentre,
  tr.AssociateLevel,
  tr.IssueDate,
  tr.TrouserSize,
  tr.TrouserLength,
  tops.CostCentre,
  tops.AssociateLevel,
  tops.IssueDate,
  tops.TopSize,
  sh.CostCentre,
  sh.AssociateLevel,
  sh.IssueDate,
  sh.ShoeSize
from
 Trousers tr
  full outer join
 Tops
  on
   tr.EmployeeID = Tops.EmployeeID
  full outer join
 Shoes sh
  on
   tr.EmployeeID = sh.EmployeeID and
   Tops.EmployeeID = sh.EmployeeID
where
 (tr.RowNum is null or tr.RowNUm = 1) and
 (Tops.RowNum is null or Tops.RowNUm = 1) and
 (sh.RowNum is null or sh.RowNum = 1)
```

Comment: Wow thanks for your effort. Sorry that was my first entry and I was in a bit of a rush when I posted it. Didn't mean for it to sound ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1
  TrouserSize, AssociateLevel
FROM 
  Employee
WHERE
  EmployeeID = '54664LSS' AND
  TrouserSize IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  IssueDate DESC

SELECT TOP 1
  TopSize, AssociateLevel
FROM 
  Employee
WHERE
  EmployeeID = '54664LSS' AND
  TopSize IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  IssueDate DESC
```

(Sorry I edited this sql about 6 times until I came up with what I think is the answer)

Assumptions - there is only one issue date column. You can have more than one item issued on the issue date, but you dont need to see those results together (otherwise we will have to group the unioned results). If there wasnt an item issued, a null is placed in the column.

Not sure what your logic will be if the AssociateLevel changes between clothing issues

Comment: Thanks for your response I have not yet tested it but basically I wanted to construct a new table with the output of the sql and make reports from that. So I don't think I can really specify what the exact employee ID is going to be as I will need to do it for 2000+ employees.This is one of the reasons why I'm finding it so confusing.

Comment: I have tested the SQL but it doesn't run, says there is an incorrect syntax near 'UNION'. I haven't used union before so will look up how it works. Oh and also...Yes you are right, there is only one issue date per entry. :)

Comment: Ive removed the union because that cant be combined with the order by.